# SED extract first occurance after 2 patterns match

Tags: awk, sed, csh

I'm trying to use c-shell (I'm afraid that other option is not available) and SED to solve this problem. Given this example file with a report of all some tests that were failing:

```
============
test_085
============
- Signature code: F2B0C
- Failure reason: timeout
- Error: test has timed out

============
test_102
============
- Signature code: B4B4A
- Failure reason: syntax
- Error: Syntax error on file example.c at line 245

============
test_435
============
- Signature code: 000FC0
- Failure reason: timeout
- Error: test has timed out
```

I have a script that loops through all the tests that I'm running and I check them against this report to see if has failed and do some statistics later on:

```
if (`grep -c $test_name $test_report` > 0) then
  printf ",TEST FAILED" >>! $report
else
  printf ",TEST PASSED" >>! $report
endif
```

What I would like to do is to extract the reason if $test_name is found in $test_report. For example for test_085 I want to extract only 'timeout', for test_102 extract only 'syntax' and for test_435 'timeout', for test_045 it won't be the case because is not found in this report (meaning it has passed). In essence I want to extract first occurrence after these two pattern matches: test_085, Failure reason:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extract "*Failure reason*" for the specified *test name* - short **awk** approach:

```
awk -v t_name="test_102" '$1==t_name{ f=1 }f && /Failure reason/{ print $4; exit }' reportfile
```

- `$1==t_name{ f=1 }` - on encountering line matching the pattern(i.e. *test name* `t_name`) - set the flag `f` into active state
- `f && /Failure reason/` - while iterating through the lines under  considered *test name* section (while `f` is "active") - capture the line with `Failure reason` and print the reason which is in the 4th field
- `exit` - exit script execution immediately to avoid redundant processing

---

The output:

```
syntax
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you! I don't actually need the test name to be printed, just the reason of failure so I took out print t_name. Is is possible to detail a bit the command?

Comment: Thank you once again! All make sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can try handling `RS` and `FS` variables of `awk` to make the parsing easier:

```
$  awk -v RS='' -F='==*' '{gsub(/\n/," ")
    sub(/.*Failure reason:/,"",$3)
    sub(/- Error:.*/,"",$3)
    printf "%s : %s\n",$2,$3}' file
```

output:

```
 test_085  :  timeout
 test_102  :  syntax
 test_435  :  timeout
```

If you don't care the newlines, you can remove the `gsub()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you have input that has attributes with name to value mappings as your does, the best approach is to first create an array to capture those mappings (`n2v[]`) below and then access the values by their names. For example:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { RS=""; FS="\n" }
$2 == id {
    for (i=4; i<=NF; i++) {
        name = value = $i
        gsub(/^- |:.*$/,"",name)
        gsub(/^[^:]+: /,"",value)
        n2v[name] = value
    }
    print n2v[attr]
}

$ awk -v id='test_085' -v attr='Failure reason' -f tst.awk file
timeout

$ awk -v id='test_085' -v attr='Error' -f tst.awk file
test has timed out

$ awk -v id='test_102' -v attr='Signature code' -f tst.awk file
B4B4A

$ awk -v id='test_102' -v attr='Error' -f tst.awk file
Syntax error on file example.c at line 245

$ awk -v id='test_102' -v attr='Failure reason' -f tst.awk file
syntax
```